# Why FirstOrDefault method is not returning any object from a list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I have following code:

```
var tmpList2 = msdbc.Pressure.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value < 0);
if (msdbc.Wetness.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value < 0) != null ||
    msdbc.Pressure.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value < 0) != null)
    throw new CustomExeptions.IncorrectDataException("Submited data are incorrect!");
```

I'm sure, that `tmpList2` contains objects with properties containing negative values (checked in data watch), but `FirstOfDefault` method is still returning null. Why? Is my predicate incorrect?

msdbc is database context (using entity framework).

Comment: Check if msdbc.Pressure contains items.

Comment: When you want to throw exception?

Comment: Im throwing exception, because I wanna catch it in my unit test and assert whether data passed to database are correct.

Comment: When you say it is returning null, at which step it is returning null. In the first statement or in the if statement.

Comment: Just some recommendations on how to improve the readability of your code: 1) You name your variable `tmpList2` although it seems to contain a single item (and then you don't use that value later on)?  2) `msdbc.Wetness.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value < 0) != null` can be rewritten as `msdbc.Wetness.Any(p => p.Value < 0)`, which is more readable.

Comment: If you use `var isDbNotEmpty = msdbc.Pressure.Any()` you will be sure that your BD contains values.

Comment: You said that `tmpList2` contains values, but in first line you get data from Database. Maby in database is no value. And witch `FirstOrDefault` return null?

Comment: Got it! I didn't realized, that values i've passed (from test solution) are not yet saved in DB, so data context was empty... Thank you!